# `App` - not retrieves the store static value

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

my app component, not retrieves the store default value at all. any one help me?

here in my `index.js` file:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Provider, connect } from "react-redux";
import store from "./Store";
import "./styles.css";

function App(props) {
  console.log("propps", props);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox{props.count}</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}

const getState = state => {
  console.log(state); //getting empty object instead `count`
  return state;
};

connect(
  getState,
  null
)(App);

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  rootElement
);
```

[Live Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/x0nmyo1kw)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const ConnectedApp = connect(
  getState,
  null
)(App);
```

then render `ConnectedApp` not `App`